# Нужно неравномерно увеличить изображение поверх других изображений css в слайдере

Tags: javascript, html, css, анимация, tilda

мне нужно при наведении на полупрозрачную кнопку (которая расположена на картинке) увеличить эту картинку на весь контейнер-блок со всей галереей картинок без затемнения фона и прочее: [image: Исходное изображение] Чтобы по итогу вышло что-то типо этого: [image: Первый вариант] и [image: Второй вариант] (Только картинки должны растягиваться на весь блок, здесь я не очень хорошо показал, наверное стоило скриншот из фигмы сделать, а не пытаться в фотошопе разобраться) В чём проблема? Их две:

1. Весь этот целиковый блок с 4 картинками и текстом слева от большой картинки помещён в блок слайдера-галереи и при нажатии стрелки вправо (нет на скриншоте) весь слайде должен уходить влево и картинки тоже и на этом месте появляется вторая галерея с таким же увеличением.
2. Непонятно как располагать блоки с картинками (на каком слое), чтобы картинка которая в данный момент увеличивается - перекрывала все другие картинки в этом блоке.
   P.S. Потом я хочу всё это перенести на Tilda чтобы в случае необходимости можно было менять картинки

Comment: Как сами пытались сделать? Добавьте используемый HTML и CSS как снипет кода (горячие клавиши в редакторе `Crtl + M`).